# Facebook Canvas App: Requests with Object

Tags: javascript, facebook, canvas, sdk, request

I have been following the Facebook documentation on how to create a Requests dialog with the action_type: send

[Facebook Requests documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.1)

I want to replicate this piece of code here:

```
Sending requests explicitly stating an action and object:

FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
   message: 'Take this bomb to blast your way to victory!',
   action_type:'send',
   object_id: 'YOUR_OBJECT_ID'  // e.g. '191181717736427' 
}, function(response){

   console.log(response);
});
```

I have created an Open Graph with the following:

```
Action type: send
Object type: gift
```

However, I am not sure what the 'OBJECT_ID' is referring to.

I've tried publishing an Open Graph and then using the response ID I get from the POST and inserting it in the OBJECT_ID but still get the error

```
Object with ID '...' cannot be retrieved.
```

I've also tried inserting a Facebook Page ID and failed.

I've successfully managed to create a basic Request dialog with just a message but when I try to send an object/gift with it, I hit the above error.

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'm stuck with the same problem. Have you figured it out??

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure on this as I don't use this feature, but I did set up an action and an object in my app to try to help you out.  Once I created an action and an object, I also created a custom story linking the two together (that's the only way I could figure out how to link them).  Once this had been done, I clicked on the `Get Code` link available from `Action Types` under `Open Graph` and it shows this:

```
Code for Action

https://graph.facebook.com/me/CANVAS_URL:send?
access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&
method=POST&
bomb=http%3A%2F%2Fsamples.ogp.me%2FNUMBERSNUMBERSNUMBERS
```

Perhaps the number at the end of the link is the object ID?  I'm just speculating as I'm not sure, but perhaps give that a try.  It would be the number after `%2F` which is the URL encoded value for a forward slash.

I also just noticed you could change the platform; the above was for HTTP while the below would be for PHP:

```
$response = $facebook->api(
  'me/CANVAS_URL:send',
  'POST',
  array(
    'bomb' => "http://samples.ogp.me/NUMBERS"
  )
);
// handle the response
```

The PHP example shows the number more clearly as it does not have the URL encode.

Answer (score 0):

Will just try answering the the object_id part, from where you can get this from or create one.

If you read the facebook documentation for [App Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.2) titled - "Creating objects for requests", here they have mentioned how to create custom objects types from your facebook dashboard which is under Open Graphs.

They have also mentioned the use of [Object Browser](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/object-browser). Here if you select the app name, Object Owner and types, from the lists, it will list all the object ID that you can use to pass in apprequests dialog.

Comment: Useful answer, yet your link to creating object for requests as of comment date says: `Custom Open Graph stories are deprecated in Graph API 2.8. Graph API 2.7 and lower will support custom Open Graph stories according to the following schedule...`